# Why this isn't spam

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, spam

I have flagged some answer like this one as spam which was declined. Can anyone explain why this is no spam?

[image]

The Definition says

> Exists only to promote a product or service, does not disclose the author's 
>   affiliation.

in my opinion this doesn't answer the question and in only links to a git repository of the user.

Comment: The user **discloses it is their own project**. They are misguidedly posting their project everywhere, but it is not undisclosed solicitation of business.

Comment: I guess to mod who handled the flag thought that "I developed" matches "an answer clearly discloses poster's affiliation with the product " (from the dupe answer).

Comment: @MartijnPieters ok thanks for the Explanation. That was definitly the last flag on stackoverflow from my side.

Comment: And also it is a github link pointing to an Open Source repository

Comment: @MartijnPieters you closed using your mod power and then why it is showing a [discussion] gold badge? which indicates that you dupe hammered?

Comment: @SagarV I have a gold badge in the discussion tag. Having expertise in a tag counts too; it was dupe hammered.

Comment: so, mod can use both dupe and mod priv. to close. new knowledge

Comment: It is tiresome, in the goode olde days a flag just meant "somebody that can do something about it, have a look here".  That got convoluted into having to bring the right kind of apples too, with endless debates about the apples and about none of them being tasty enough anymore.  Just keep in mind that you *can* do something about it yourself, you have enough rep to vote to delete.  That's what I do.

Comment: @SagarV see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268288/show-the-gold-badge-in-addition-to-the-diamond-when-a-moderator-closes-as-a-dupl

Comment: @MartijnPieters one more question on this why all the answers were deleted?

Comment: @Jens: they had more flags on them; they were basically link-only answers. Link gone, solution gone.

Comment: @MartijnPieters In my list of possible flags there is no Option link only answers since a very long time.

Comment: @Jens: Both "Not an answer" and "Very Low Quality" are fine flags to cast on such answers.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have tried it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44739686/3636601) and it was also declined. So it is very hard to decide for me which flag should be used.

Comment: @Jens: but there is still a solution there without the link.